# Print HTML report with header and footer on all pages - Firefox

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I tried several methods but none seems to work properly. I have a html report and I need to print the report with header and footer in every page. I need this working in firefox!

**Solution 1:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
#footer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:100%"> header content </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%"><table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><br>
              &nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%"> main content </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="footer" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%"> footer content </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution 1 problems:** The main content overlies the footer.

**Solution 2:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}
tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group;
}
}
@media screen {
thead {
    display: block;
}
tfoot {
    display: block;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>header content</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> main content </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>footer content</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Solution 2 problems: The footer stays just below the main content, not always in the bottom of the page as I wish.

Any help or other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Try: http://csslayoutgenerator.com/

Comment: Works well for web, but for print I still have the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution for my problem. I'll put it here for those who have the same problem.
In my first example we just have to assign tfoot the height we want for the footer.

For example:

```
<tfoot>
   <tr> 
    <td width="100%"> 
     <table width="100%" border="0"> 
       <tr> 
         <td colspan="4">
         <br>&nbsp;
         </td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
         <td colspan="4">
         <br>&nbsp;
         </td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
         <td colspan="4">
         <br>&nbsp;
         </td> 
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </tfoot>
```

Or assign one class and put the height you want.

Comment: You set the width in the example, but say that you sets the hight..? could you elaborate the solution in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

if I right understands you, try:
set footer height to 50px (100px,200px... anything)
and add to main content margin-bottom:50px (footer height)

This must exclude overlying content with footer.

Comment: Sorry, in this case for print with a position fixed footer, this method don't works..